# When I'm Publishing data using publisher(WSO2 Data Analytics Server)getting Exception

Tags: java, apache, networking, wso2, wso2-das

**When I'm Publishing data using publisher(WSO2 Data Analytics Server)getting following Error.Code running fine.But publisher will not push any data to server,my 192.168.##.##:7711,7611 ports also active.can some one help me please.**

```
root@musni-hp:/opt/wso2publisher/LogDirectoryPublisher/binary# ./runlogpublisher.sh &
            [3] 10921
            root@musni-hp:/opt/wso2publisher/LogDirectoryPublisher/binary# .
             INFO [main] (LogFileDataPublisher.java:146) - Total number of files to process 2
             INFO [main] (LogFileDataPublisher.java:150) - Current file being processed 1 File Name 16063004000005_team_cdr.log
             INFO [main] (LogFileDataPublisher.java:176) - Total events: [116]
             INFO [main] (LogFileDataPublisher.java:150) - Current file being processed 2 File Name 16063005000006_team_cdr.log
             INFO [main] (LogFileDataPublisher.java:176) - Total events: [529]
            ERROR [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://192.168.##.##:7611-pool-4-thread-1] (DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99) - Error while trying to connect to ssl://192.168.##.##:7711
            org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://192.168.##.##:7711
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:37)
                at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 192.168.##.## on port 7711
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
                ... 9 more
            Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
                ... 11 more
            ERROR [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://192.168.2.18:7611-pool-4-thread-1] (DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:46) - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.##.##:7711
            org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.##.##:7711
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://192.168.##.##:7711
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:37)
                at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
                ... 6 more
            Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 192.168.##.## on port 7711
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
                at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
                ... 9 more
            Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
                ... 11 more
             INFO [DataBridge-ReconnectionService-pool-1-thread-1] (DataEndpointGroup.java:333) - No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
```

screen shots : 
   [telnet and Shellscript reads the log files fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1htkp.png)

[runlogpublisher.sh -inside of shellscript,properties file & keystone we are taking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE7tu.png)

Comment: What is not clear on `ConnectException: Connection refused`? Either you are trying to connect to wrong IP/port, or there is another obstacle (firewall?) preventing connection.

Comment: Here I attached screen shots with you @Jozef Chocholacek

Comment: In first screenshot the telnet is working for 192.168.2.26 7711 but your log publisher is using different ip 192.168.2.18.Try to use correct ip address in the publisher code.

Comment: sorry for the mistake,attached correct screenshots @ajanthan

Comment: I don't see any issues with given details. But in your screenshot I can see that keystore is not there. Did you get that in the same time?

Comment: yes,I attached scn for your reference@Bhathiya

Comment: It seems that in your config.properties file you have not defined the ssl url. You have given as tcp for both the url s (with different ports) defined. And  Try giving ssl instead of tcp for the second url for EventRecieverUrl. i.e. replace "tcp\:192.168.2.26\:7711" with "ssl\:192.168.2.26\:7711"